# What is CINCFAIRMED?

Tags: military, bosnian-war

In JAG 01x13 "Defensive Action" 09:30, a character says "This just came in from CINCFAIRMED." (Online episode summaries suggest that this is the correct spelling, but don't give a definition.) Given that the action takes place in Bosnia in the 90's, it would make sense for it to be "Commander in Chief... Mediterranean", but I am unable to find this term in lists of military acronyms or elsewhere on Google (even with alternate possible spellings based on the pronunciation).

Is it a position that only existed at that time, perhaps related to IFOR? Or was this an error in the show?

Comment: It could be a deliberate invention by the show to avoid people nit-picking that the CINC was actually named such and such or wasn't involved with X or Y.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't [COMFAIRMED](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/agency/navy/fairmed.htm) (with an O and no extra C)? That appears to be a NATO position. If not, you might have better luck looking for similar NATO acronyms.

Comment: [jag episode summaries](https://jag-summaries.blogspot.com/1996/)uses the same abbreviation.  Although interesting, I don't think this can be answered by historical sources and methods (other than to say that there appears to be no record of that position existing). Might be that you'd have more success in the TV & Media stack exchange?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a history question.

Comment: "There is no such recorded position" would be a satisfactory answer, so I think it can be answered by historical sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seemingly typical USN acronym, but the the show's writers played a little fast and loose; the correct modern acronym would be ComFAirMed which falls under CinCNavForEur (Commander in Chief US Naval Forces Europe), described [here](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/agency/navy/fairmed.htm#:%7E:text=COMFAIRMED%20is%20a%20subordinate%20commander,medical%20facilities%20in%20the%20Mediterranean.).

But to decipher the acronym they gave . . .

CinC - commander in chief -
FAIR - Fleet Air -
MED -  Mediterranean

This would be the commander of fleet air assets, usually land based, being logistic and patrol aircraft, primarily, in the Mediterranean Sea area, not to include those assets aboard carriers which would fall under CINCLANTFLT.

One can find without looking hard for CINC's

CINCPACFLT - Commander in Chief Pacific Fleet

CINCLANTFLT - Commander in Chief Atlantic Fleet

for FAIR, especially in a WW2 context, as that was when the various Fleet Air commands were first established . . .

ComFAirWest - Commander Fleet Air West (located in San Diego)

ComFAirSeattle - Commander Fleet Air Seattle

ComFAirNorf - Commander Fleet Air Norfolk

etc.

MED is the common USN acronym for Mediterranean, describing the sea itself or as a boundary for operations.  When USN ships are deployed to the Mediterranean Sea, it is described in the vernacular as a "Med Cruise".

See [Glossary of U. S. Naval Abbreviations](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USN/ref/OPNAV_29-P1000.html#title)

Note that one CinC does not report to another.  Nowadays CinC's report to the SecDef and through that office to the President.